# i get the texture in opengles,now i want to rotate the texture,but failed

Tags: opengl-es, rotation, textures

I have a piece of code that get the texture of opengles

```
   -(void)textureFromName:(UIImage *)name
    {
    CGImageRef      brushImage;
CGContextRef    brushContext;
GLubyte         *brushData;
size_t          width, height;
    GLuint          texId;

    brushImage = [name CGImage];


    // Get the width and height of the image
      width = CGImageGetWidth(brushImage)*4;
    height = CGImageGetHeight(brushImage);

// Make sure the image exists
    if(brushImage) {
    // Allocate  memory needed for the bitmap context
    brushData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
    // Use  the bitmatp creation function provided by the Core Graphics framework.
    brushContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(brushData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(brushImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    // After you create the context, you can draw the  image to the context.
    CGContextDrawImage(brushContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), brushImage);
    // You don't need the context at this point, so you need to release it to avoid memory leaks.
    CGContextRelease(brushContext);
    // Use OpenGL ES to generate a name for the texture.
    glGenTextures(1, &texId);
    // Bind the texture name.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

    **/*************************************************/
    //rotate the texture,but didn't work
    static float angle = 1;       
    if(angle < 200)
        angle+=2;
    else
        angle = 1;
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(angle,.0,0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    /*************************************************/**

    // Set the texture parameters to use a minifying filter and a linear filer (weighted average)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // Specify a 2D texture image, providing the a pointer to the image data in memory
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, brushData);
    // Release  the image data; it's no longer needed
    free(brushData);
}
```

}
here is the problem:
        //rotate the texture,but didn't work
        static float angle = 1;
        if(angle < 200)
            angle+=2;
        else
            angle = 1;
        glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef(angle,.0,0.0,1.0);
        glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        glTranslatef(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
i want to rotate the texture,but doesn't work,so
someone can help me ? thank you evry much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your code with the wrap set to GL_CLAMP. You should be able to see the texture rotate.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.5,0.5,0.0);
glRotatef(angle,.0,0.0,1.0);
glTranslatef(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: than you,this is a Graffiti demo.I tried this method，but not work,i need call the function -(void)textureFromName:(UIImage *)name in - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event,so i can draw a line with a pretty effect，thank you again!

Comment: yes, if your intention was to achieve some kind of animation effect,  then you have to call the function..im just curious to know, are you calling this (void)textureFromName:(UIImage *)name every time for the same image??

Comment: yes,Do you know the GLPaint demo? i used (void)textureFromName:(UIImage *) get a texture,so i can draw a line with texture,if can rotate the texture in touchesMoved function,the line will Looks Uneven，(the image for texture is Irregular)

Comment: im not aware of GLPaint demo, but i checked the code. Since you are using the same texture, you don't have to call (void)textureFromName:(UIImage *) again and again just for the sake of rotation. You already have an handle to that texture. Instead you could move your rotation code block to - (void)renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end.

Comment: Thank you so enthusiastic，I've tried this method ,but still failed